# Rails aborted error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting an error while running the following test:

```
$ rails test:models
```

Below is a sample of the error:

```
Run options: --seed 40805
Finished in 0.046173s, 21.6575 runs/s, 21.6575 assertions/s.
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:9:in `aggregated_results'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:597:in `report'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is about randomizing the execution order of tests. You can explicitly use them like this:[Reference here](http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/09/25/minitest-ruby-1-9s-test-framework/)

```
rake TESTOPTS="--seed=40805"
```

or Try it.

```
SEED=40805 rake test
```

Comment: Mayur thanks for the response!  While it didn't totally worked it reduced the amount of errors significantly.   $ SEED=51024 rake test Run options: --seed 51024 # Running:  rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:9:in `aggregated_results'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-5.10.2/lib/minitest.rb:597:in `report'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/minitest-reporters-1.1.9/lib/minitest/minitest_reporter_plugin.rb:26:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.

Comment: Any other suggestions?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Nate This is actually a bug in rails, revealed by minitest update to 5.10.2.

Specify in your Gemfile:

`gem 'minitest', '~> 5.10', '!= 5.10.2'`

after that `bundle update minitest`